# How to get Tumblr blog's "Posts remaining till next reset" and "next reset time"

Tags: java, php, tumblr

I have seen websites for checking a Tumblr blog's post limits such as "posts remaining till next reset" and "next reset time" (There is a limit of 250 in Tumblr until the next reset time).

I read the Tumblr api (http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2) and did not find a way to get those information.

Anyone know any method of getting those information using Java or PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Post Limits

**Background**

Sadly there isn't any official documentation on this, but my understanding is as follows:

- Limit is 250 posts / reblogs per 24 hours
- Limit for photo posts maybe 150 posts per 24 hours (see references)
- Limit is reset at midnight
- Timezone for midnight is not the users timezone, it is Eastern Time.

Using http://postlimit.com/ I get the following stats:

```
Posts since last post-limit reset: 0
Posts remaining till next reset: 250
Time left until next reset: 19 hour(s) 39 min(s) 51 sec(s)
Time Zone: Europe/Dublin
Time in that Zone: 9:20 AM (Mon, Apr 28)
```

The above confirms the timezone isn't user related, otherwise `Time left until next reset` would be `14 hours 39 mins`. I believe the timezone used is `EST` or `GMT - 04:00`.

**Is there an official method to get this?**

I don't believe there is an official method to get the limit / reset time, you will have to calculate it yourself. One way to calculate it:

- Use the API to call the last 250 posts.
- Work out time offset from `EST`. The API says date format is `GMT`???
- Work out if the last 250 posts fall into the current 24 hour period.
- If they do, the limit has been reached, work out the time remaining to limit reset is reached.

**Are you sure?**

Honestly, no. I had to look at this recently and the above is from my own research (mainly pulled from Google and Tumblr posts). However, if anyone has anything to add, please do. I am more than happy to update the answer, make this a wiki etc, as it really is undocumented.

**References**

- Tumblr API - http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts
- Postlimit.com - http://postlimit.com/
- Photo Post Limit - http://unwrapping.tumblr.com/post/46305045121/post-limit-250

Comment: Ok! It is a GOOD answer! I'm going to implement it!

Comment: @BuntuLinux Happy to help. If you find something else / different about it, do let me know so I can update it. Good Luck!